# MvcSiteMapProvider: url not working with Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MvcSiteMapProvider 4.6.18.0.

I'm able to generate the menu.

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Home" action="Index" area="" imageUrl="glyphicon glyphicon-home" description="Colony dashboard">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Profile" controller="Profile" action="Index" imageUrl="glyphicon glyphicon-user" description="My Profile" />
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Administration" imageUrl="fa fa-lock" description="" clickable="false" controller="" area="" url="2" key="administration">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Users Management" controller="Users" action="Index" area="Admin">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Add New User" controller="Users" action="Create" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Users" action="Details" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" preservedRouteParameters="id" >
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" controller="Users" action="Edit" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" key="Users_Edit" preservedRouteParameters="id" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Delete" controller="Users" action="Delete" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" preservedRouteParameters="id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Dashboard url is http://localhost/Home/Index which is correct.

Users Management url should be http://localhost/Admin/Users/Index but instead it is resolved as http://localhost/Home/Admin/Users/Index

it should not have Home in the url.

I have search through SO and other forums, I couldn't find a solution.

Area Route:

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Default Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Initialize", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Project.Controllers" }
        );
```

Please, how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to determine what the problem is, since you are not showing the call to the `node.Url` property, nor have you posted your routes. But, you should be aware that `MvcSiteMapProvider` uses .NET routing to generate the `node.Url` output, so if your routing config is incorrect your URL will be incorrect. See [this section](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Controlling-URL-Behavior#using-net-routing) of the documentation to troubleshoot URL generation in MVC.

Comment: BTW - ImageUrl is a special field that resolves the value as a URL, you should not be putting a CSS class in there. Use [custom attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node) for that purpose.

Comment: Nothing about the routes you have posted would explain the problem. 1) Is `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` being called before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` like it should? 2) Are there any other routes or RouteAttributes in your application that you haven't posted? 3) Does `@Html.ActionLink("Users Management", "Index", "Users", new { area = "Admin" })` in a view resolve the URL correctly?

Comment: Thanks NightOwl, the problem was number 3. I was passing the area to url.action().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NightOwl888.

The problem was in my helper class.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string ToHtmlString() {
    string output = "";
    TagBuilder tagBuilder = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._icon)) {
        tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("i");
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass(string.Concat("menu-icon ", this._icon.Replace("/", "")));
        output = string.Concat(output, tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
    tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
    tagBuilder.AddCssClass("menu-text");
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml = this._text;
    output = string.Concat(output, tagBuilder.ToString());
    if (this._isDeropDown) {
        tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("i");
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass("menu-expand");
        output = string.Concat(output, tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
    tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    if (this._isDeropDown) {
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass("menu-dropdown");
    }
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(this._html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", urlHelper.Action(this._actionName, this._controllerName, new { area = this._areaName }));
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml = output;
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString()).ToString();
}
```

Changed:

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", string.Concat(this._areaName, urlHelper.Action(this._actionName, this._controllerName)));
```

To:

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", urlHelper.Action(this._actionName, this._controllerName, new { area = this._areaName }));
```